# Recurrent neural networks (Hopfield-like) with short limit cycles

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Standard [Hopfield networks](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hopfield_network) exhibit stable patterns (states) which are attractors of a dynamic system. I wonder how to modify standard Hopfield networks such that they exhibit stable limit *cycles* as attractors. Since for [binary neurons](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hopfield_network#Binary_neurons) (to which I'd like to restrict my question) each attractor is a limit cycle of some length (because state space is finite), the question asks for "short" limit cycles (significantly shorter than the size of the state space, but longer than $1$).

Is there a simple standard [recurrent neural network](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Recurrent_neural_network) (of which - optimally -  Hopfield networks would be a special case, e.g. for some parameter $\lambda \rightarrow 0$) that typically gives rise to short limit cycles?

How many of these can there be (compared to the number of neurons), and how big can their added up [basins of attraction](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Basin_of_attraction) be (compared to the size of state space)?

**Toy example**:

[image]

This mini network has one stable state $(00)$ with basin of attraction $\{00,11\}$ and one limit cycle $(10,01)$ with basin of attraction $\{10,01\}$

Comment: If what you are asking is for an example of such a thing, it should be easy to find one.  Pick any function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that has a short limit cycle, then find a neural network that approximates $f$.  Since neural networks are universal function approximators, such a neural network must exist.  If you're asking how many can there be, I don't think such a question is well-defined, since the weights are real numbers and thus the number is presumably infinite (in fact, uncountable, most likely).  Or maybe I've misunderstood -- I know nothing about Hopfield networks.